# <input> onmouseenter don't work with left mouse button in Firefox, IE, Edge

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

This code works perfect in Chrome but not in Firefox, IE, Edge.

```html
<input type="text" readonly onmouseenter="this.style.backgroundColor='red'" onmouseleave="this.style.backgroundColor='white'">

<input type="text" readonly onmouseenter="this.style.backgroundColor='red'" onmouseleave="this.style.backgroundColor='white'">
```

When I press the left mouse button on the first INPUT and move over the second INPUT - the color changes correctly in Chrome. Not in Firefox, IE, Edge (second INPUT not recorded onmouseenter event).

With the right and middle mouse button, works code perfect in all broswers.

Do you know how to fix it? Why it does not work?

(I can use only raw javascript in this project)

Comment: This seems to work already: https://jsfiddle.net/xfoa3dkh/

Also, you don't have to click inside the `<input>`s.

Comment: What are you trying to do again? Are you holding down the button while moving your mouse over the second input? Because that's actually trying to drag the first input over the second, which those other browser are trying to do, or it's trying to select both. Both of which cancel the mouseenter event.

Comment: I am doing something like a simplified excel table. Cells are INPUT.
[example_gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/xT1XGUJWbTdkeB0vXG/giphy.gif)

Comment: Finally, I used a `<div>` instead of `<input>`.